# Place of different directives (like include, inherit, etc) inside a Yocto recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am learning Yocto myself and I could not figure out one thing from suggested Yocto docs: is it really important to have directives like *include*, *inherit* and so on in their specific place inside a recipe?
I mean: sometimes I see Yocto's recipes where *inherit* is the last statement of a recipe. I decided to keep up with that tradition in my own recipes, but once I used *native* class and I got an error as Yocto told me it should be the last class to include. But I could not understand why.

So my question is: what are the rules for in-recipe placement of different BB directives? Okay, I know about variables and their late or in-place expansion, but what about class inheritance, include/require and so on? Will it have any consequences if I make all my recipes have *include* on the top, before all statements?
Thanks!